# Is it faster (or more efficient) to create a variable rather than use an operation in the output?

Tags: java, variables, output

I'm currently creating a program (actually, I've already finished it) which converts kiloBytes into bytes and MegaBytes.

It's fairly easy, and it took me seconds to create it. My issue is that I managed to find a vast array of solutions, which made me wonder, which is more efficient.

this is a sample of the bytes output:

```
System.out.println(kiloByte + " KB = " + (1024 * kiloByte) + " bytes");
```

but imagine if I had to print the bytes on different places, and instead of that I had to have something like

```
System.out.println((1024 * kiloByte) + " " + (1024 * kiloByte));
```

In my opinion, it would be preferable to create a variable, rather than doing the same operation twice, hence looking like this:

```
int vbyte = 1024 * kiloByte;
System.out.println( vbyte + " " + vbyte);  // vbyte as a variable for bytes
```

although, I am not completly certain that that is the case, so, am I correct to assume the first version is slower than the second?

Comment: In other words, if I am going to repeat the same operation several times, is it preferable to create a variable and then call it instead?

Comment: You could test it and share the result with us.

Comment: Generally operations would only matter if the call is issued a multitude of times (e.g. in a loop), also you might look into `String` concatenation versus using a `StringBuilder`. But all of that really matters if you continuously repeat the information, on a regular basis it doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: @CeilingGecko no need for a StringBuilder here, javac will do it for you automatically.

Comment: @arghtype Testing without a secure envoirement (such as guaranteeing that decreases of speed are merely the program's fault is next to impossible in this case ;)

Comment: @assylias is right, while it may be true, it really isn't needed though, but I appreciate the help regardless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you don't need to worry about such operations. The code which you have written will be automatically optimized by compiler; and so this won't make your program slower.

In this case, the compiler will generate a **temp variable** and store the value into **temp** var before the print operation. This **temp variable** will replace (1024 * kiloByte) in the string to be printed; ans so, the operation is not done multiple times. This is a type of basic optimization done by compilers called **"Common_subexpression_elimination"** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination).
And usually Java compiler is very good in optimization compared to other compilers.

If you want to know more about General compiler optimization techniques, you can read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler

Before passing to println, the compiler will even generate a temp variable for the combined string which you are printing. [Click here](http://programming4.us/desktop/452.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting the awnser, I meant to do it right away, but stackoverflow didn't let me for another 'x' minutes, and then I forgot :/, anyway, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

The JVM can probably figure out that they are the same calculation and perform it only once. But even if it didn't, a multiplication takes less than a nanosecond on any modern CPU so you won't notice the difference, especially while printing, which takes several orders of magnitude more time than that...

Now from a readability perspective, using well named variable is generally a good thing so go with option 2.

Comment: I agree with you regarding readability (I actually have a line under it explaining the process). But, glad you mentioned that the JVM does that, I had no idea of that, many thanks :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning to express intentions with good variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the first version *might* be slower than the second but with such a trivial example it would be almost unnoticable and might even get optimized by the compiler. When you have more complex and expensive operations then reusing the value will yield noticably better performance.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, although, it would be overkilling if I had used the operation 'n' times to a point where it would actually matter, as this just a simple example =)

Comment: @user3126359 agreed but that _n_ would have to be _really_ huge in order to matter and in that case there are probably other operations that will slow down your code even more, e.g. string concatenations. ;)

Comment: Exactly, I did this just for the theory, usually when I program simple things I try to think on how I could improve them so when I reuse the code it's more efficient

Comment: @user3126359 reflecting on your code is always good, just take care not to fall into the premature optimization trap. :)

Answer (score 1):

We have a concept of time space tradeoff in data structures; whose essence I would like to use to explain you the answer.

**Time is inversely proportional to memory.**

When you are assigning a computation to a variable, it calculates the computation only once and the stored result is usable in many places in your program by just using that variable. Here we used memory to make up for time used in computation.

The other part where you put computation at multiple places in your program, causes repetitive calculation at multiple places. Here we sacrificed time to save memory.

Time space tradeoff is applicable to all computer languages and is basis of complexity minimization of programs of all kinds. Its upto us what we choose, time efficency or space(memory) efficency depending upon the situation involved in the problem.